How did Jacobi find his connection between theta functions and $q$?
I was 'reading' (I can't actually read german, but I can read math!) Jacobi's derivation of the ODE for $y(q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2} $.
On page 2 of the paper Jacobi states the following as an axiom of sorts that was considered to be obvious at the time. I am asking how to prove and see this result.
The result is if
$$ y(k) = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2 (\varphi)}} }  $$
and
$$ \ln \left( \frac{1}{q(k)} \right) = \pi \frac{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{\cos^2(\varphi)+k^2 \sin^2(\varphi)}}}{ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2(\varphi)}}} $$
Then $$y(k) = 1 + 2q(k) + 2q(k)^4 + 2q(k)^9 ... \rightarrow y = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2} $$
So I tried to derive this the usual way anyone in 1846 would. I went to my copy of mathematica on a new macbook pro and implemented:
y[k_] = Sqrt[2/Pi * Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - k^2 * Sin[s]^2], {s, 0, Pi/2}]] 
Q[k_] = Exp[-Pi *( Integrate[  1/Sqrt[Cos[s]^2 + k^2 Sin[s]^2], {s, 0, Pi/2}]/
 Integrate[  1/Sqrt[1 - k^2 Sin[s]^2], {s, 0, Pi/2}] )]

And then attempted to compute the series via the techniques here
Series[y[InverseFunction[Q][k]], {k, 0, 10}]

To my great surprise, after 10 minutes, there was no answer. Whatever Mathematica was computing was simply NOT converging.
So I am quite spooked now. If my CAS can't handle this, how on earth did Jacobi manage to find and verify this result back in the day? And why is this considered obvious? I can't find a citation for this in the text, he just starts here and then picks up.
If anyone can enlighten me on how this can be derived by hand I would be very grateful.
For those that want to find Jacobi's work, the work in particular is cited as  K. G. J. Jacobi, J. Reine Angew. Math. ( = Crelle’s Journal.) 36 (1847), 97-112 in Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 2 Page 282. And can be found here.
The ODE can be found here

I'm pretty sure Mathematica came out in 1848, so there's no way Jacobi would have had access to that.

Jacobi used Python

I haven't found a derivation yet but Paramanand Singh's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441501/how-does-one-express-jacobi-theta-functions-in-terms-of-elliptic-integrals clarifies the matter a fair bit. Essentially my question is "given the elliptic integral form of $\vartheta_3$ and the nome, how to prove the nome-power series of $\vartheta_3$  directly?"

I wrote a series of blog articles that walked through everything.

Jacobi got the product expansion $y=\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1})^2$ rather easily using his product expansions of elliptic functions, but to get the series form $y=\sum q^{n^2}$ took a bit more effort and he introduced theta functions for that purpose and incidentally discovered his triple product identity in the process. But then he gave another direct proof of the triple product identity so that one can get the series form from the product form.

The best approach here is to study Jacobi's Fundamenta Nova which is now available in English.
I will mention in brief Jacobi's approach towards elliptic integrals, elliptic functions  and theta functions. Jacobi develops the theory of transformation of elliptic integrals in great detail and in so doing he reaches the notion of modular equations for transformations upto degree $5$. He then proceed to give the transformation formulas for a general prime degree  and realises that this needs a bit of analytical approach (compared to the algebraic approach needed for transformations of degree upto $5$). And for the same he inverts these integrals to get elliptic functions and the values of these elliptic functions are used to give the transformation formulas for elliptic integrals.
A lot of these formulas involve finite series as well as finite products and following the conventions of his time Jacobi uses a limiting procedure to convert these formulas to infinite series and product expansions for elliptic functions. In this process we see the birth of parameter $q$ called nome and its relation to the elliptic integrals. In particular the identities linking elliptic modulus $k $ and elliptic integral $K$ to the nome $q$ are derived in a purely algebraic manner.
I have explained some part of the theory in my blog posts (search for "Jacobi" in the archives page and read the posts if you have sufficient time, but don't forget to read Jacobi's original work linked earlier).
An alternative approach based on arithmetic-geometric mean is also available on my blog and you can have a look at post 1 and post 2.
It is worth pointing out that Ramanujan developed his theory of elliptic and theta functions using just algebraic manipulation of series and products and I have discussed his approach as well in my blogs and you should have a look at that as well by searching for Ramanujan in archives page. He uses hypergeometric functions and their transformations in very smart manner to develop his theory.

The result Jacobi is using is one of the most important results in elliptic functions: the problem of inversion. It was obvious at the time but far from axiomatic.
First recall the definition of the elliptic integral of the second kind:
$$ E(\phi,k) = \int_{0}^{\phi} \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta }d \theta$$
if we define:
$$ \Delta\theta =  \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta } $$
then
$$ E(\phi,k) = \int_{0}^{\phi} \Delta\theta d \theta$$
since $\phi = \operatorname{am}(u)$ and by definition $\sin\phi = \sin(\operatorname{am}(u))=\operatorname{sn}(u)$ and
$$\Delta \phi = \Delta \operatorname{am}(u) = \operatorname{dn}(u)\tag{*}$$
and since
$$ u = \int_{0}^{\phi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$$
$$ \frac{du}{d\phi} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}  \implies d\phi = \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}du = \Delta \phi du \tag{**}$$
Therefore
$$ d\sin \phi = \cos \phi \Delta \phi du$$
From these results we can transform $E(\phi,k)$:
First, from $(*)$ we can make the change of variable $\displaystyle \sin\theta = \operatorname{sn}(v)$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
 E(\phi,k) &=& \int_{0}^{\phi} \Delta\theta d \theta\\
&=& \int_{0}^{F(\phi,k)} \operatorname{dn}(v) d \theta \quad \textrm{ from } (*)\\
&=& \int_{0}^{F(\phi,k)} \operatorname{dn}(v) \Delta\theta dv \quad \textrm{ from } (**)\\
&=& \int_{0}^{F(\phi,k)} \operatorname{dn}^2(v) dv 
\end{eqnarray*}
From this motivation we define a new function, called the Jacobi Epsilon function:
$$  \mathcal{E}(u) =  \int_{0}^{u} \operatorname{dn}^2(v) dv \tag{1}$$
Clearly
$$ E(\phi,k) = \mathcal{E}(F(\phi,k)) \; \textrm{ or } \; E(\operatorname{am}(u),k) = \mathcal{E}(u)$$
and we can also define these two fucntions:
the Jacobi Zeta function
$$ Z(u) = \int_{0}^u \left[\operatorname{dn}^2v -\frac{E}{K}\right]du =  \mathcal{E}(u) - \frac{E}{K}u = u\left(1-\frac{E}{K}\right)-k^2\int_{0}^{u}\operatorname{sn}^2(v)dv \tag{2}$$
and the theta function
$$ \Theta(u) = \sqrt{\frac{2k'K}{\pi}}e^{\int_{0}^{u} Z(v)dv} \tag{3} $$
In modern notation:
$$\Theta(u) = \vartheta _4\left(\frac{\pi u}{2K}\right)$$
From (3) it is easy to see that
$$ \Theta(0) = \sqrt{\frac{2k'K}{\pi}} $$
additionally, it can be proven that
$$ \operatorname{dn}(u) = \sqrt{k'} \frac{\Theta(u+K)}{\Theta(u)}$$
So, if $u=0$
$$ \boxed{\Theta(K) = \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}d\phi}}$$
$\Theta(K(k))$ is the function $y(k)$ you are looking for.
It can be proven that $\operatorname{sn}$ can be expanded as trigonometric series:
$$ \operatorname{sn}(u) = \frac{2\pi}{kK} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{1-q^{2n-1}} \sin\left[(2n-1)\frac{\pi u}{2K}\right] \tag{4}$$
where $\displaystyle q = e^{-\pi\frac{K'}{K}}$
Squaring this series and from (2) and (3) it can be shown:
$$ \Theta\left(\frac{2Kx}{\pi} \right) = 1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n q^{n^2} \cos(2nx) $$
with $\displaystyle x = \frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\boxed{ \Theta\left(K\right) = 1+2q+2q^4+2q^9+... }$$
The steps to prove $(4)$ and transform $(3)$ are not difficult but not trivial.

thank you so much for putting this together! I am going to work through the steps so I feel like its clear in my head and then will accept :)

Can you walk me through why $E(u) = \int_{0}^{u} dn(v)^2 dv$ is true? I assume first that $E(u) = E(u,k)$ since only $E(\phi,k)$ has been defined up to this point. From here then it follows that $E(u) = E(u,k) = \int_{0}^{u} \sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin(v)^2} dv$  Now what I need to show is that $dn(v)^2 = \sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin(v)^2}$. Now you gave a large number of possible identities to leverage here, so I'm sure there's a way to make this work but i'm just not seeing what the obvious path here should be.

Also I think you have a typo. Your $\sin$'s probably should be squared in the top half of your answer (although do let me know if i'm wrong). Now with that out of the way I can write that $E(u) = E(u,k) = \int_{0}^{u} \sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin(v)^2} dv = \int_{0}^{v} \Delta v dv$ so I need to argue that $\Delta v = dn(v)^2$

@SidharthGhoshal Sorry for not being clear. In reality, $E(u)$ is a different function than $E(\phi,k)$ although deeply related. Please see the motivation above; I added more context. This new function is often called the Jacobi Epsilon function with the notation $\mathcal{E}(u)$, although Jacobi used the notation $E(u)$ and considered this new function a reinterpretation of $E(\phi,k)$.
And regarding the typos, you're right, I corrected them.

@SidharthGhoshal Regarding the path, this is the way this was proven in Jacobi's time. There are alternative solutions. For example, you could start defining  $\displaystyle \Theta\left(u\right) = 1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n q^{n^2} \cos\left(\frac{n\pi u}{K}\right)$, define also $\displaystyle \operatorname{sn}(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \frac{H(u)}{\Theta(u)}$ where $H(u) = \Theta(u+iK')$ and then prove that $\displaystyle \Theta(K) = \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}$. This path may be easier but the number of steps is somewhat the same. I can elaborate on this way if you wish.

A look at elliptic functions in Mathematica help files reveals that there has  not yet done much work.
Worse, in the latest versions they have a new implementation, that tests -  at any internal instant of an argument passing -, if the argument may be a PossibleZero or a PossiblePeriod. If you trace an evaluation, the evaluation trees grow beyond limits in memory and time. Windows often terminates the Mathematica app without comment with an memory access exception.
Not even the simplest tables of modulus/argument transforms are implemented.
Elliptic specialists are a rare species and make their money in cryptography.
For Jacobis competence in Fourier series manipulation in 1846: Very new stuff with great controverses between the famous originators about applicabilty besides finite series and no idea about how far reaching complex Fourier transform would evolve into real functional analysis later.
The idea to transform the complex  variable $z$, so that the full period becomes the unit interval - by multiplication with $2 \pi K(k)$ - is quite natural.
In this representation one can handle the elliptic algebra as a rational field by formal Fourier series manipulation.
I spent a month during last Christmas to get clear the Mathematica 13.3 elliptic definitions by their numerics after I complained for the new non-periodic implementation of $\text{am}(z,1/m)$. The essential function is the $\text{dn}$-function with its antiderivative the amplitude, so that $\text{sn = sin am, cn = cos am}$ and all other rationals using the trigonometric rationals as $\text{sec, tan}$ , etc can be easily implemented in the first quarter period.
   Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[
   {Sin[y],
    Cos[y],
   JacobiDN[y/(2\[Pi])(4EllipticK[1.0 m]),m],
   EllipticTheta[{1,2,3,4},  y ,EllipticNomeQ[m]]}],
  {y,0,2\[Pi] },
   Ticks->{{0,\[Pi],2\[Pi]},{-1,0,1}},
   PlotLegends-> Placed[{
   "sin",
   "cos",
   "dn",
   "Subscript[\[Theta], 1]",
   "Subscript[\[Theta], 2]",
   "Subscript[\[Theta], 3]",
   "Subscript[\[Theta], 4]"},Left],
    LabelStyle->{FontSize->9,OutputForm}],
  {{m,0.25},0.0,1.2},ControlPlacement->Top]


The ComplexPlot yieldslattice of poles and zeros
  m = RandomReal[]; mprime = 1 - m; 
Sqrt[mprime] EllipticTheta[1, (2 \[Pi])/Sqrt[m] x , m]/
             EllipticTheta[4,  x , E^(-\[Pi]^2 mprime/m)]  

$$\frac{0.628288 \vartheta _1(8.07627 x,0.605254)}{\vartheta _4(x,0.00160131)}$$
  ComplexPlot3D[
    JacobiDN[z/(2 \[Pi]) (4 EllipticK[1.0 m]), m], 
   {z, 0, 2 \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] I} ]


  ComplexPlot3D[
   EllipticTheta[ 1,  z ,EllipticNomeQ[m]]/
   EllipticTheta[ 4, z ,EllipticNomeQ[m]], 
    {z,0,2\[Pi]+2\[Pi] I},
     AxesLabel->{"x","y","abs dn"}]


As the different colors representing the complex argument suggest, there is a phase factor missing.

Thank you for enlightening me on why Mathematica failed. How do I see that derivation via formal Fourier series manipulation? I’m not skilled with modular forms or elliptic functions and so even with your hint I don’t know how to begin.
